# PDFBox IllegalArgumentException: No glyph in font Webdings

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, truetype

I'm trying to write to a PDF in Webdings font using PDFBox. What I'd like to appear is the symbol that is represented by character A in Webdings. However, I get an IllegalArgumentException saying that there's no glyph in my Font for the given character. Am I missing something around encoding or is Webdings simply not supported?

I use PDFBox 2.0.17, many solutions to similar problems seem outdated. I can verify Webdings in the Character Map tool and it works in programs such as word.
The actual problem I have is not with Webdings but another non-public font and I don't have any alternatives to that one. Using Webdings as the problem pattern seems to be the same.

```java
PDFont font = PDFontType0Font.load(doc, new File("pathToWebdings.ttf"));
PDPageContentStream cos = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);
PDStreamUtils.write(cos,"a", font, 100, 100, 100, Color.BLACK);
cos.close();
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+0061 (a) in font Webdings

Comment: There is no character "A" in webdings. You need to use the unicode character for whatever you want to choose, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdings , probably \u1F3D7

Comment: And for the small a (checkmark), it's probably \u2714.

Comment: I get `No glyph for U+2714 (✔) in font Webdings`.
I also tried to reverse the process for the actual font I'm using and created a PDF (from Word) with the symbol I need. Then I read that with PDFBox and cast the char to int to obtain the unicode character. It returns 61505 which I'm then escaping with [SurrogatePairCalculator](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm) but still end up with `No glyph for U+61505`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also get `WARNING: cmap format 4 subtable is empty` when loading it - does that indicate that the problem is a different one from Webdings?

Comment: I don't have much time right now (I could reproduce it but need to investigate), but what does work is this: use the font `PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS` and then `\u2714` works.

Comment: I found it by looking at the webdings font with DTL OTMaster 3.7 light. It is \uf061 .

Comment: That worked with Webdings, thanks! So the problem is actually identifying the correct unicode character in the font. Any idea why my approach above for the other font (61505) isn't working? Unfortunately I don't have third party font tools. Should I ask it as separate question?

Comment: Maybe 61505 is decimal. In Hex this is F041 which sounds familiar, i.e. "41" would be an "A". Re the warning - don't bother.

Comment: Indeed it seems that 61505 is decimal, works just fine with "\uf041". I'm just confused as to how I would recognize whether it's decimal or not when casting it. Anyways, thank you so much - all your answers are on PDFBox are invaluable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at it with [DTL OTMaster 3.7 light](https://www.fontmaster.nl/legacy/) (this is free and very useful), the checkmark will work with `\uf061` with the `webdings` font (tested in Windows 10).

[image]
(screenshot looks a bit weird because I have a 4K monitor)

Alternatively, use `PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS` and then `\u2714` will also work.